# Dialog in Custom Adapter in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, custom-adapter

I have one custom adapter that have one checkbox and one textview.I want when user clicked on one row one alert dialog pop up and user enter data.I use following code in activity and worked fine:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.floordialog,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.floordialog));

    floornum = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.floordialog_floornumber);
    unitnum = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.floordialog_unitnumber);
    Button next = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.floordialog_next);
    Button cancel = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.floordialog_cancel);


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("floors");
    builder.setView(layout);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.create();

    flooralert = builder.create();
    flooralert.show();

    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
```

but i cant use in MyCustomAdapter because i Dont extend activity, how can solve my problem?
and this is my CustomAdapter

```
        public MyadapterForListFloor(Activity a, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Integer> Floornum) {
    super();
    unitdialog = new UnitDialog();
    this.entries = Floornum;
    this.activity = a;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return entries.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.unitview, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.UnitTextview);
        holder.checked = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.unitCheckbox);

        v.setTag(holder);

        holder.checked.setTag(entries.get(position));
        holder.text.setTag(entries.get(position));

        holder.checked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewHolder obj = new ViewHolder();
                obj.checked = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.unitCheckbox);

                getid = (Integer) v.getTag();

                if (isChecked(getid))
                {
                    obj.checked.setChecked(true);
                    unitdialog.DialogForFloor();
                    Urban.selectedRow.add(getid);
                }
                else
                    Log.d("in else onclick", "**");
            }

            private boolean isChecked(int getid) {

                for (int i = 0 ; i< Urban.selectedRow.size() ; i++)
                {
                    if (Urban.selectedRow.get(i)== getid)
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
        holder.text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.checked.performClick();
            }
        });
    }
    else 
    {
        ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).checked.setTag(entries.get(position));
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        getid = (Integer) holder.checked.getTag();

        Log.d("geti is", String.valueOf(getid));

        if (checkBoxRefresh(getid))
            holder.checked.setChecked(true);


        else
            holder.checked.setChecked(false);

    }

    final String str = String.valueOf(entries.get(position));
    if (str != null) {

        holder.text.setText(str);

    }

    return v;
}

private boolean checkBoxRefresh(int FloorNum) {
    Log.d("urban.selectedrow.size is", String.valueOf(Urban.selectedRow.size()));
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Urban.selectedRow.size() ; i++)
    {
        if (Urban.selectedRow.get(i) == FloorNum)
            return true;
    }
    return false;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    CheckBox checked;

}
```

}

Comment: Pass your context to MyCustomAdapter. Show your code for MyCustomAdapter..

Comment: So what's the problem? What do you want to do that you can't do?

Comment: I have CustomAlertDialog Too, that i need findviewById that dont recognize

Comment: how can define LayoutInflater and how can refer to my edittext in alertdialog?

Comment: You can create a separate method for your custom alertdialog in your class and you can invoke that method whenever you click onItem of your ListView or whichever you have used by implementing `setOnItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 3):

In Class CustomAdapter you need to declare a class level variable mContext

```
Context mContext;
```

Create a constructor:

```
public AdapterAudio(Context mContext) {
    super();
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
```

When you call CustomAdapter from Activity, "Activity_Main.this" is Context you need

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(Activity_Main.this);
```

Don't pass `getApplicationContext()`, we need to pass `MainActivity.this` to the constructor as `AlertDialog class` need this to show alert.

If you pass `getApplicationContext()` or `getContext()` then you will get the following error:

```
W/System.err: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Now, pass the mContext to show alert:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setTitle("floors");
    builder.setView(layout);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.create();

    flooralert = builder.create();
    flooralert.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

You are already passing your Context to `MyCustomAdapter`.

Comment: its worked , but how can define my View? i use final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.floordialog,
    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.floordialog));

Comment: Same thing. activity.findViewById.

Comment: but activity layout and alertDialog layout is separated, i dont Think So Its Work !!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass necessary `Context` to your `adapter` from activity and use that context in your dailog.

Here@

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(here will be your context which is from activity);
```

*As you mention in your comment that you  have to custom dialog and you have to do findviewById.*

you can do like this@ (It just an example)

**Updated**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(your_activity_context);
View view = your_activity_context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
builder.setView(view);

 Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
```

Comment: i need LayoutInflater to refer to my edittext in alertdialog, can you explain to me how can create LayoutInflater and View because findviewbyid dont recognize.

Comment: I try to put first part of my code that is for my alert dialog in the second part that is my CustomAdapter, if you think that is better way to do that please suggest me.tnx