# Calling a function in an Activity, from a custom class

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Below is my customer class which extend PagerAdapter:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private Vector<View> pages;
private static activity2 act2;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, Vector<View> pages) {
    this.act2 = new activity2();
    this.mContext=context;
    this.pages=pages;
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    View page = pages.get(position);
    page.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Log.i("TAG", "This page was clicked: " + position);

            act2.receiptAction(position, mContext);
            return false;
        }

    });

    container.addView(page);
    return page;
}
}
```

Code at my Activity2 (which need to call from CustomPagerAdapter)

```
public void receiptAction(final Integer CurrentPage, final Context tContext){
    if (CurrentPage > 0) {

        final ApplicationInfo thContext = tContext.getApplicationInfo();
        final AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(tContext.getApplicationContext());

        dlgAlert.setTitle("Receipt");
        dlgAlert.setMessage(receiptPool.get(CurrentPage));

        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //();
                //startActivity(lastcreated.getIntent()); //REFRESH INTENT
            }
        });
        if (!receiptPool.get(CurrentPage).contains("_(Canceled)")) {
            dlgAlert.setNeutralButton("Void", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dlgAlert.create().cancel();
                    final AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(tContext.getApplicationContext());
                    dlgAlert2.setTitle("Void ?");
                    dlgAlert2.setMessage(receiptPool.get(CurrentPage));

                    dlgAlert2.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            cancelOrder(receiptPool.get(CurrentPage), dlgAlert2);
                        }
                    });
                    dlgAlert2.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //();
                            //startActivity(lastcreated.getIntent()); //REFRESH INTENT
                        }
                    });
                    dlgAlert2.setCancelable(true);
                    dlgAlert2.create().show();
                }
            });
        }

        dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Rebet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                finish();
                MainActivity.currentReceipt = receiptPool.get(CurrentPage);
                MainActivity.isRebet = true;
                intent = new Intent(tContext.getApplicationContext(), activity1.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });


        dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
        dlgAlert.create().show();
    }
}
```

But, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:310)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:279)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:76)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:213)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:240)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:463)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
        at com.M28.activity2.receiptAction(activity2.java:633)
        at com.xsys.xobj.CustomPagerAdapter$1.onTouch(CustomPagerAdapter.java:37)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8956)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2410)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:5303)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2559)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1767)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2866)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2520)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9167)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4706)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4544)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4201)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRoot
```

How can i call the function at Activity2 from CustomPagerAdapter ?

Comment: can you upload the Manifest...and styles

Comment: error pertains to theme than what you actually asked for. As i see you should be extending AppCompatActivity in your activity and also the theme should have parent set to Theme.AppCompat . Try to us ethe latest support library , there is a documented issue in support lib v23.2.0 .

Comment: my activity2 is extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: Why is 'activity2' static in your PagerAdapter?

Comment: @Mdlc actually I have no idea how to do it, and I just try and error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution for this, check out the answer given by Faisal Shaikh ([Dialog in Custom Adapter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755847/dialog-in-custom-adapter-in-android))

Answer (score 0):

This public void receiptAction(final Integer CurrentPage, final Context tContext) method change to like that

```
public static void receiptAction(final Integer CurrentPage, final Context tContext)
```

then it call from CustomPagerAdapter like this

```
Activity2.receiptAction(current_page_number, mContext);
```

Comment: I can't set it to static, because i need to call other function in Activity2 in the alertDialog action.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

use above code in manifest for Activity2.

Comment: I am asking for calling alertDialog function in my Activity2,  from my custom class...

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. Try adding theme in manifest for Activity2.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the appcompat library and support libraries in gradle file, you might not have included these libraries i.e.

```
dependencies 
{
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}
```